# QTableView, glitch on showing hidden rows

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview

I'm not sure either it's some kind of bug\glitch or I'm doing something wrong.
I have some hidden rows in the table and on click I want them to appear but result you can see on the picture below.
[image: before click] [image: after click]

This effect occurs only when slider is scrolled till the end. Glitch disappears if I change focus to another window or when I scroll table up until it goes out of view.

Here is my code:

```cpp
connect(tableView_, SIGNAL(clicked(const QModelIndex &)), this,
    SLOT(onTableClicked(const QModelIndex &)));

for(int i = 0; i < table_->rowCount(); i++)
{
    if(i%table_->typesNumber())
        tableView_->hideRow(i);
}

...

void DumpsComparisonWindow::onTableClicked(const QModelIndex& index)
{
   ...
   tableView_->showRow(index.row() + i);
   ...
}
```

**UPDATE:** to make it possible to test I have created cut version of my project, you can find it here: https://gitlab.com/JuicyPussy/qtableview_glitch

Comment: did you try calling tableView_->update() or tableView->repaint() ?

Comment: @PabloYaggi neither of them help, still same result

Comment: please provide a minimal functional example

Comment: @PabloYaggi, uploaded to git. Thank you for a hint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After showing or hiding any rows make the model notify about the change in the layout to all views. You do that by calling layoutChanged.

```cpp
void DumpsComparisonWindow::onTableClicked(const QModelIndex& index)
{
   ...
   tableView_->showRow(index.row() + i);
   ...
   table_->layoutChanged(); //add this
}
```

Comment: layoutChanged() is a signal of QAbstractItemModel, but the answer helped in some way

Comment: yes, it is a signal, and you are allowed to emit it, and when you do the glitch goes away. Remember it is not necessary to use 'emit' to emit a signal, you can just call it like I show you. Cheers !